# Watir : recognizing image button

Tags: xpath, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to get a repetitive task done using Watir and I am having difficulties, need your help with it. I have the below code for the button:

```html
<button class="ppm_button " onclick="submitForm('page','more=1');" type="button">
  <img border="0" align="absmiddle" title="Add and Select More" alt="Add and Select More" style="width: 11px; height: 8px; background: url("ui/uitk/images/nde.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;" src="ui/uitk/images/s.gif" >
  &nbsp;Add and Select More
</button>
```

I try to get the xpath using firebug and use the same xpath to run the script on ff, it fails. I am having hard time giving an appropriate xpath to recognize the object.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide your xpath please. And try something like this `//img[@title='Add and Select More']`

Comment: I recommend against using xpath unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: yeah, avoid xpath, I've never had to use it with watir. Code reads better without it.  If neither answer below works for you, is this thing inside a frame by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get this avoiding xpath.

Try using a Watir selector like:

```
b.img(:src => "ui/uitk/images/s.gif")
```

You should then be able to append whatever you want to do with the element on to the end e.g. `.click`

This is going off of the available properties at https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir but I'm not sure what version of Watir you're using, or how up to date that list is.

According to it you could also use:

```
b.img(:alt => "Add and Select More")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid xpath unless nothing else works, it tends to make for code that is ugly and hard to read compared to other ways of identifying the element you need.

I think what @anonygoose has ought to work, but if it does not another thing to try would be click the button itself, which could be done as follows  (note I am presuming you want to click the button, otherwise replace .click with some other method as appropriate)

```
browser.button(:class => 'ppm_button ').click
```

or

```
browser.button(:text => /Add and Select More/).click
```

or if for some weird reason neither of those work, you could use one of these

```
browser.img(:src => "ui/uitk/images/s.gif").parent.click

browser.img(:alt => "Add and Select More").parent.click
```

If none of those work for you please edit your question and include which ones you have tried and what message you get as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work!

`browser.img(:src => "url of the base image").parent.click`. Just need to mention the url(in the inspect element) of the image, that the thumbnail uses.